# What does ErrorCode: 180008 SubscriberFailureDescription: Error Code: 27 - Subscriber was excluded by Suppression logic. mean

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Some of our sends in a journey are showing this error message:

```
ErrorCode: 180008 SubscriberFailureDescription: Error Code: 27 - Subscriber was excluded by Suppression logic.
```

The email send does not have any explicitly associated suppression list. How can I find how/where these contacts are being suppressed.

Comment: Do you have a [suppresion list](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_a_suppression_list.htm&type=5) configured to exclude emails from recieving email sends ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states these particular Subscribers are a part of Suppression List, you should manually check the list(s) in Email Studio.

In Email Studio go to Subscribers tab and select Suppression Lists from the dropdown menu.
Over there you'll find BU specific lists.

Even if you haven't added anyone yourself, it's likely these Subscribers [**added themselves**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subscribers_on_suppression_list.htm&type=5) if they clicked on the One-Click-Unsubscribe link or - if you have ***Public*** Suppression Lists, then they may have gotten to it via Preference Center.

In addition, you can check if there is an [**Auto-Suppression**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_auto_suppresion_lists.htm&type=5) configured on your Marketing Cloud instance, these have separate lists and custom configuration. You'll find these in the Email Studio > Admin tab.

Comment: this would be my answer too. My guess is that the Subscriber email address exists in an auto-suppression list. Note that auto-suppression lists can *either* be defined at a child BU level or globally at the Parent BU. To validate this, go to Email Studio > Admin > Send Management > Auto-Suppression Configuration.

Comment: yup it was the auto-supression configuration, thanks!